# Why golang slice is empty after initialization?

Tags: go, slice

My question here is why the slice is empty in another func when the slice is global to the file?

Here's a piece of code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vec3 struct {
    x float32
    y float32
    z float32
}

var a []Vec3

func main() {
  a := make([]Vec3, 0)

  a = append(a, Vec3{2.0, 3.0, 4.0})
  a = append(a, Vec3{3.4, 5.6, 5.4})
  a = append(a, Vec3{6.7, 4.5, 7.8})

  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", a)
  doSomethingWithA();
}

func doSomethingWithA() {
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", a)
}
```

Output:

```
[{x:2 y:3 z:4} {x:3.4 y:5.6 z:5.4} {x:6.7 y:4.5 z:7.8}]
[]
```

[This](https://repl.it/Fd6K/9) is a repl.it link too, if you want to take a look.

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Since you're using a:= make(...) you may be shadowing the global var. Try with a = make(...)

Comment: Interesting. It seems to be working on this example. But not in my current example that I'm working on.

Comment: Updated the snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have redefined it here:

```
a := make([]Vec3, 0)
```

To use the same variable you should assign a value with `=` but not declare a new variable with `:=`

```
a = make([]Vec3, 0)
```

#### [Short variable declarations](https://tour.golang.org/basics/10)

> Inside a function, the := short assignment statement can be used in place of a var declaration with implicit type.

Comment: It seems to be working on this example. But not in my current example that I'm working on. What happens when slice is inside a struct instance that is in the global map? I'm getting an empty slice.

Comment: @redpix_, it will be less extrasensory experience if you ask a question with concrete snippet which produces the problem. Please, update your question with the snippet which you just described.

Comment: @redpix_, btw your repl.it snippet works well with removed variable re-declaration.

Comment: Updated. Kind of ripped the code out of a project. It's much more complex than that.

Comment: @redpix_, well... now it is completely new question about `append` function behavior. Roll back the original question and ask new. I'll give you an answer.

Comment: I'm not able to delete the question I'll roll back and ask new.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135291/discussion-between-i159-and-redpix).

Answer (score 3):

You are re declaring a, so actually you not initializing the global var, try:

```
a = make([]Vec3, 0)
```

Comment: It seems to be working on this example. But not in my current example that I'm working on. What happens when slice is inside a struct instance that is in the global map? I'm getting an empty slice.

Comment: Updated the snippet.